# parsing ifconfig into lists

Tags: python, list

I want to parse ifconfig so that I am only left with the vlans that have an IP address assigned.
I want the following data from each vlan, the interface name, the IP address and the mac address (mac in a  converted format). These should be stored in a list of lists. A list for each vlan.

So far I have just made one list with the IP and the interface name for each vlan. However I feel I am going off track and doing this in a bad way, any suggestions?

Desired output:

```
[['vlan1', '192.168.2.2', '0013.F200.0058'], ['vlan100', '192.168.110.2','0013.F200.0058'], ['vlan20', '192.168.30.2','0013.F200.0058']]
```

Current output:

```
 ['vlan1', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.2.2', 'vlan100', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.110.2', 'vlan20', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.30.2']
```

I know I can turn this flat list into nested lists easily, but I feel it should be done in the step before this.

EG but I think this is bad:

```
i=0
new_list=[]
while i<len(data_list):
    new_list.append(data_list[i:i+3])
    i+=3
```

Code:

```
import re
a = """

vlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2188 (2.1 KiB)  TX bytes:383156 (374.1 KiB)

vlan100   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          inet addr:192.168.110.2  Bcast:192.168.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2683 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:375620 (366.8 KiB)

vlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vlan20    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          inet addr:192.168.30.2  Bcast:192.168.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4389760 (4.1 MiB)  TX bytes:3112376 (2.9 MiB)
"""

    for paragraph in a.split('\n\n'):

    #mac = re.search(r'HWaddr\s+(\S+)', paragraph)
    #c.append(mac.group(1))
    if "vlan" in paragraph and "inet addr:" in paragraph:
        b= []
        b.append(paragraph.split())
        for i in b[0]:     
            if "addr:" in i:
                ip = re.search(r'addr:(\S+)', i)
                c.append(ip.group(1))
            if "vlan" in i:
                c.append(i)   
            if  re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d:(\S+)', i):
                it = iter(i.split(':'))
                i = ".".join(x+y for x,y in zip(it,it))
                c.append(i) 
     print c
```

Comment: why not `grep`, `regexp`?

Comment: And why list of lists? Wouldn't it be better to create dict of lists? Key of dict would be name of vlan and every list will contain mac and ip.

Comment: @Wookie88 Basically I want to print out each list in a table format and I'm used to using lists.  Since the length and data varies it's easy to just refer to the index. Open to using anything though.

Comment: Depending on your version of `iproute2` you may be able to use a seemingly undocumented `ip -d link` which will list the vlan ids per interface and you won't be relying on the interface naming convention reflecting the actual vlan tag in use.

Comment: @MattH Thanks I'll have a look

Answer (score 7):

```
import re
a = """

vlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2188 (2.1 KiB)  TX bytes:383156 (374.1 KiB)

vlan100   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          inet addr:192.168.110.2  Bcast:192.168.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2683 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:375620 (366.8 KiB)

vlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vlan20    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:F2:00:00:58  
          inet addr:192.168.30.2  Bcast:192.168.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4389760 (4.1 MiB)  TX bytes:3112376 (2.9 MiB)
"""

c = []
for paragraph in a.split('\n\n'):

    ma = re.compile("(vlan\d+).*HWaddr ([^ ]+).*addr:([^ ]+)", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

    result = ma.match(paragraph)

    if result != None:
        vlan = result.group(1)
        mac = result.group(2)
        ip = result.group(3)

        m = mac.split(':')
        mac = m[0] + m[1] + "." + m[2] + m[3] + "." + m[4] + m[5]

        #print "vlan:", vlan
        #print "ip:",ip
        #print "mac:", mac

        c.append([vlan, ip, mac])

print c
```

result:

```
[['vlan1', '192.168.2.2', '0013.F200.0058'], ['vlan100', '192.168.110.2', '0013.F200.0058'], ['vlan20', '192.168.30.2', '0013.F200.0058']]
```